# How do you access content in a word document? (like Grammarly does)

Tags: windows, ms-word

I want to create a program that works like an autocomplete box for Microsoft Word. For that, I need some way of reading the contents of the page and getting the positions of words. I know that Microsoft has made a Javascript API for creating plugins in the form of side panes, but that's not what I'm after.

Grammarly manages to read the contents of the document and even underline specific words.
[image: Grammarly in word]

Maybe they have some agreement with Microsoft? Or could they be using some hacky solution? I did try to use win32api with both Python and C++ but didn't succeed.

Comment: Suggest your question is rather too open-ended, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . But FWIW although I've obviously heard of Grammarly, I've never used it , and I don't know which versions of Word it works with. If it's basically Windows desktop word, the chances are they have to work at the *Windows messaging* level to if they want their dialog boxes to move when the user does something like scroll down their document.

Comment: Thank you, you’re probably right. It seems like this question better fits the Super User stack